# SQL Server - Combine two select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, Semester1 and Semester2.
Semester1:

| StudentId | SubjectId |
| --- | --- |
| abc | sub1 |
| def | sub1 |
| ghi | sub1 |

Semester2:

| StudentId | SubjectId |
| --- | --- |
| abc | changedSub1 |
| def | sub1 |
| ghi | changedSub2 |
| newStudent1 | sub2 |
| newStudent2 | sub3 |

I am trying to write **a single Select statement** such that it selects **rows from Semester2** that have:

1. New StudentIds - i.e., StudentIds in Semester2 that are not in Semester1. So the result from this requirement should be Semester2's `newStudent1` and `newStudent2` rows.

**AND**

2. Changed SubjectIds - i.e., SubjectId are different for the same StudentId between Semester1 and Semester2. So the result from this requirement should be Semester2's `changedSub1` and `changedSub2` rows.

I have been able to write two separate queries to select the 2 requirements separately:

```
-- Part 1
SELECT * FROM Semester2
    WHERE StudentId NOT IN ( SELECT StudentId from Semester1 );

-- Part 2
SELECT Semester2.StudentId, Semester2.SubjectId 
FROM   Semester2
JOIN Semester1
  ON (Semester1.StudentId = Semester2.StudentId)
  WHERE Semester1.SubjectId <> Semester2.SubjectId;
```

How can I combine the two queries? Or if there is a better/easier/clearer way to write both requirements as a single query (without combining my above queries), how do I do that?

Comment: can you not just use union? select studentid, subjectid from semester1 union select studentid, subjectid from semester2. union will get rid of the dupes

Comment: OR... just `UNION ALL` between your two existing SQL statements which will meet all of your requirements.

Comment: You can combine these queries with `union`. Just remove the first semicolon and write the keyword between queries. The queries need to have matching column types and count, so they can be matched to each other.

Comment: You have to tell us *why* you want to combine two working queries? Are you looking for better performance? Elegance? Clarity? I myself have been tempted to make "sophisticated" code only to discover simpler would be better.

Comment: Aside from the answers provided, what you have is a bad design.  You should have 1 table that has the semester, student and Subject IDs (with lookup tables for actual semester, student and subject descriptions).  What would you do after you got to the 17th semester as school goes on for years...  But direct answers of union will get what you need for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a single query with an *outer join* should suffice

```
select s2.*
from semester2 s2
left join semester1 s1 on s1.studentId = s2.studentId
where s1.studentId is null or s2.SubjectId != s1.SubjectId;
```

Comment: `where s1.studentId is null` - Why null?

Comment: Because you want rows where there is no match (the two "newstudent" rows) - hence where the join results in a null value.

Comment: Just a note - NULLIF can combine these conditions. NULLIF(S2.SubjectId,S1.SubjectId) returns NULL if s1.SubjectId = s2.SubjectId and returns s2.SubjectId otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it in a single query using a join if UNION doesn't count for "single query":

```
SELECT s2.* 
  FROM Semester2 s2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Semester1 s1
         ON s2.StudentId = s1.StudentId
         AND s2.SubjectId = s1.SubjectId
 WHERE s1.StudentId IS NULL;
```

The WHERE clause will make it so only results where there isn't a perfect match in Semester1 appear.

Comment: `WHERE s1.StudentId IS NULL` - Why null?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN will give you all the rows on the left side, and any results from the right side.
So, if you did select *, you would get every row that's in S2, and all columns from S1, but in the S1 columns, they will be NULL if there's no matching row in S1.
That would give you all 5 rows in your example, with only def having the S1 columns populated, as it's the only one that matches perfectly.
By saying WHERE s1.StudentID IS NULL, you pull all records where there is no matching record in S1.  So effectively, anything where they either changed their subject, or where they are new.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to extend your "Part 1" query a little. Right now it excludes *all* students from semester 1, but you only want to exclude students from semester 1 that do not have changed subjects in semester 2.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Semester2
WHERE StudentId NOT IN (-- Student ids with same subject from semester 1
                        SELECT StudentId FROM Semester1
                        WHERE Semester1.SubjectId = Semester2.SubjectId);
```

But I haven't tested it. Please let me know if I made some terrible mistake.

Answer (score 0):

One option that requires no `UNION` (which requires scanning the table twice) and no `OR` condition (which can be slow) and no `LEFT JOIN` (which confuses the optimizer into thinking there will be multiple joined rows)

```sql
SELECT s2.*
FROM semester2 s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM semester1 s1
    WHERE s1.studentId = s2.studentId
      AND s2.SubjectId = s1.SubjectId
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest thing I can think of.

```sql
select Semester2.*
    from Semester2
        left outer join Semester1
            on Semester1.StudentId = Semester2.StudentId
    where NULLIF(Semester2.SubjectId,Semester1.SubjectId) is NOT NULL
```

NULLIF will return NULL if the two things are equal (same student had the same subject both semesters). Otherwise it returns Semester2.SubjectId. This excludes exactly what you want to exclude - students from Semester1 who didn't have a different subject in Semester2.